# Dynamic-DynamoDB not scaling down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been testing Dynamic-DynamoDB on a single table, and it does not want to scale down the provisioning.  Can anybody see what I've done wrong?

Here is the log from one cycle.  I let it run overnight...  This message sequence goes on and on.

```
2014-03-31 12:58:51,617 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned read units: 25
2014-03-31 12:58:51,683 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned read units: 25
2014-03-31 12:58:51,683 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed read units: 0%
2014-03-31 12:58:51,702 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Read throttle count: 0
2014-03-31 12:58:51,719 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-31 12:58:51,779 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-31 12:58:51,779 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed write units: 0%
2014-03-31 12:58:51,806 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Write throttle count: 0
2014-03-31 12:58:51,806 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - No need to change provisioning
```

And, here is the configuration for the table:

```
[table: myTestTable]
reads-upper-threshold: 90
reads-lower-threshold: 30

increase-reads-with: 50
decrease-reads-with: 50

increase-reads-unit: percent
decrease-reads-unit: percent

min-provisioned-reads: 5
max-provisioned-reads: 25

writes-upper-threshold: 90
writes-lower-threshold: 30

increase-writes-with: 50
decrease-writes-with: 50

increase-writes-unit: percent
decrease-writes-unit: percent

min-provisioned-writes: 5
max-provisioned-writes: 100

#maintenance-windows: 22:00-23:59,00:00-06:00

sns-message-types: scale-up, scale-down

allow-scaling-down-reads-on-0-percent: true
allow-scaling-down-writes-on-0-percent: true

#always-decrease-rw-together: true
```

The only thing I have not tried yet is setting the maintenance window times.  I assume that when they are not set, it will do updates at any time.

Update.  I found that attempt at a scale up event that happened overnight during a test.  Obviously, I'm at the max already so it didn't do anything, as I would expect.  I just don't understand why the scale down is not working.

```
2014-03-30 23:27:16,789 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed read units: 0%
2014-03-30 23:27:16,808 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Read throttle count: 0
2014-03-30 23:27:16,827 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-30 23:27:16,880 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-30 23:27:16,880 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed write units: 117%
2014-03-30 23:27:16,901 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Write throttle count: 0
2014-03-30 23:27:16,902 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Reached provisioned writes max limit: 100
2014-03-30 23:27:16,902 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - No need to change provisioning
2014-03-30 23:27:17,104 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - Sleeping 300 seconds until next check
2014-03-30 23:32:17,277 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned read units: 25
2014-03-30 23:32:17,353 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned read units: 25
2014-03-30 23:32:17,354 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed read units: 0%
2014-03-30 23:32:17,375 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Read throttle count: 0
2014-03-30 23:32:17,433 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-30 23:32:17,481 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - myTestTable - Currently provisioned write units: 100
2014-03-30 23:32:17,481 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Consumed write units: 151%
2014-03-30 23:32:17,501 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Write throttle count: 0
2014-03-30 23:32:17,501 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - Reached provisioned writes max limit: 100
2014-03-30 23:32:17,502 - dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - myTestTable - No need to change provisioning
2014-03-30 23:32:17,695 - dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - Sleeping 300 seconds until next check
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in the version.

https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb/issues/142

I will stop posting these here and use GitHub if I have any more issues.  Sebdah answers very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it may have been a bug, but if this still happens to some people, there is [a limit of how many times per 24 hour period you can scale down a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-decreasing-provisioned-throughput). Once you reach that limit, DynamoDB will not let you scale down more times and will throw an error if you try to request to do it again.